# Makefile and shell variables

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, compilation

I am defining a variable likes this in my makefile

```
target:
         @for entry in ${FOLDERSS}      ; \
         do                                       \
            COUNT=$$(( $${COUNT}+1 ))   ; \
            if [ $$COUNT -eq 1 ] ; then  \
                FOLDERS="[ -s "             ; \
                aux=`echo $$entry`      ; \
                FOLDERS+=$$aux          ; \
            else                                  \
                FOLDERS+=" [ -s "       ; \
                aux=`echo $$entry`      ; \
                FOLDERS+=$$aux          ; \
                FOLDERS+=" ]"               ; \
            fi                              ; \
         done                              ; \
     FOLDERS+=" ]";\
```

"FOLDERSS" is defined manually in my Makefile containing all the folders I need to consider for compilation. Now what I want is to execute the following:

```
deps: target
         ${AUTOGEN} -d $${FOLDERS}) -f ${AUTOCONF};\
```

where AUTOGEN is a  bash script and AUTOCONF is a configuration file. FOLDERS should write out exactly what it contains i.e. something like this:
[ -s /home/at/src/folder1 [ -s /home/at/src/folder2 ] ]
So all in all the execution of the bashscript in my makefile should have the following command:

```
./path/to/autogen -d [ -s /home/at/src/folder1 [ -s /home/at/src/folder2 ] ] -f /path/to/autoconfile
```

If I type this manually in makefile it works, however when using the double dollar symbol it seems like it is not able to evaluate the variable FOLDERS.

Does anybody has some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a slightly weird thing to want, and a very complex way to approach the problem. How's this instead?

```
folders := $(patsubst %,[ -s %,${FOLDERSS})\
    $(patsubst %, ],${FOLDERSS})

deps: target
    ${AUTOGEN} -d $(folders)-f ${AUTOCONF}
```

We declare a Make variable `folders` whose value is `${FOLDERSS}` with the string `[ -s` added before each token, followed by the same number of `]` closing brackets.

Attempting to use Bash arrays requires Make to be specifically set up to use Bash intead of `sh`; and you were not using the correct syntax to recall the values of the array. Shell variables will not persist between recipe invocations anyway (unless you take special measures to force this behavior). The [useless use of `echo` in backticks](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) is mostly harmless as such, but nevertheless an antipattern you want to avoid.

As an aside, you should not use `@` to disable printing of recipe commands, especially not while debugging complex recipes.

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense to do. Although, the folders variable does not give the desired outcome. For some reason it skips the whole path up to the folder, so it just gives folder1/ and folder2/

Comment: That seems unrelated to the code I posted. Can you show a Pastebin orsimilar of the exact code and the output you get?

Comment: So FOLDERSS = $(SRCDIR)/folder1 $(SRCDIR)/folder2

Applying what you said only give: [ -s /folder1 [ -s /folder2 ] ]
So the $(SRCDIR) is missing

Comment: Looks to me like SRCDIR is unset when this is evaluated. Here's a demo / [mcve]: https://ideone.com/xNyvM8